# Polymer 1.0 missing paper-select workaround

Tags: polymer, material-design, paper-elements

Since there is no paper-select element, is there a way of using iron-dropdown to apply material design to the below Select Type Extension Element?

```
<dom-module id="my-products">
    <template>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-products',
            extends: 'select'
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is demonstrated in the newly released paper-dropdown-element on Github:

https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu